# I don't understand why my answer deleted to my own question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I answered my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245657/php-mail-returns-true-message-accepted-for-delivery-but-the-message-is-not-se), but I do not know why it got deleted. Apparently a moderator deleted it, so I, as the asker, cannot delete it.

My answer was

> Install [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).
>
> Here is a sample on [how to send mail with PHP mailer](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/)
>
> ```
> function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) { 
>   global $error;
>   $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
>   $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
>   $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
>   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
>   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
>   $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
>   $mail->Port = 465; 
>   $mail->Username = GUSER;  
>   $mail->Password = GPWD;           
>   $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
>   $mail->Subject = $subject;
>   $mail->Body = $body;
>   $mail->AddAddress($to);
>   if(!$mail->Send()) {
>       $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
>       return false;
>   } else {
>       $error = 'Message sent!';
>       return true;
>   }
> }
> ```

Would someone be so kind as to explain what I did wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question is a troubleshooting one, but the answer appears to be a product recommendation.    Your answer would be a better one if it explained specifically why installing PHPMailer is the definitive solution to the problem you posed, rather than fixing your broken code.

Comment: The code you copy-pasted also doesn't explain how to use it here on the site. I'm sure a novice user would be confused when they copy-paste that code from your answer and can't figure out what PHP means when it says `GUSER` and `GPWD` aren't defined.

Comment: @animuson Fair point and I appreciate the fast response. But wouldn't have been better for to have left a comment explaining this rather than delete the post? And should I just repost it my answer with more detail?

Comment: Post an answer that says "This is how I fixed it," and accept the answer.

Comment: @TAAPSogeking  I'm the one who deleted, and this is the answer why. It looked like a product recommendation with a broad tutorial, and not a specific answer. I didn't know it was a self answer (I usually don't take that into account), but it seemed... off. :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber I had been working on the problem for months, and when I finally found the answer the answer, I wished to post my solution so that others could use it. In the future would you leave some sort of message, but I appreciate your criticism and I hope I have my answer better.